# Microsoft Azure Apache Web Server Not Accessible

Tags: apache, ubuntu, azure, apache2

I've created literally dozens and dozens of web servers in my day, but this is my first attempt with Windows Azure and I'm running into some problems.  I just started migrating from AWS recently.

First of all, I'm running Ubuntu 13.04.  Firewall disabled (for debugging), Apache2 installed correctly (using apt).  SSH works fine as do many other services with both the DNS hostname and public IP.  Virtual host is set up correctly and validated.  However, I cannot access the HTTP website either through the Azure provided subdomain or the virtual IP.  It just times out.

This is also my first time using Ubuntu 13.04 as well.  So, through the powers of deduction, I'm assuming there is something I'm missing either with this new version of Ubuntu or some quirk in Azure.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I found out that public IP (VIP) is no assigned in OS. Then I check another machine Ubuntu 12 LTS and Windows and again this problem. This may be your problem too. I also looking for a solution. Why you migrate from AWS what is a weakness for you?

Comment: Have you added an [Endpoint](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/how-to-guides/setup-endpoints/) for your server?! Like on port 80 (or whatever you've configured Apache to listen to)?

Comment: Your VIP will **never** be assigned to the OS! The OS has DIP (Direct IP Address). Check out [this article](http://blogs.staykov.net/2012/03/windows-azure-basics-part-2-of.html), which, although covering mainly PaaS, still represents the networking in Azure pretty well and accurate for VMs also!

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try some of this out and see how it works. With AWS, it was easy - create an elastic IP, assign it, and I was off and running. Azure seems a little different. @PeterGarett - I switched to Azure to maintain HIPAA compliance. AWS won't sign Business Associate Agreements (BAA).  There were new HIPAA rules released in January 2013 that require it and AWS isn't compliant because they refuse to sign (so far), but Azure (Microsoft) will.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

These steps to create "endpoint" works fine for all VPS:

1. open "virtual machine > endpoint > add endpoint"
2. choose "next"
3. set "name:http, protocol:tcp, public port:80, private port:80"
4. choose "complete"

and then must wait for activation and then for some time.

Comment: That works! Thanks!  Had no idea it would be such an obvious solution that I overlooked. Azure is a little different than AWS and I'm still getting accustomed to it.

Comment: how long is activation waiting?

Comment: +1 for the waiting part :) It took in my case like 5 minutes.

Answer (score 17):

If you are using Azure Resource Groups along with your VMs (which is available on the new portal) you cannot use endpoints because it's not available there, so you should follow the following to open up the HTTP port or ANY other port:

1- Select the VM that you want to manage ports on.

2- In settings, click on Network Interfaces and select your network.

3- Go to Network Security Group and select your group.

4- Add Inbound or Outbound security rules depending on what you need.

Comment: I was looking for this from a long time. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why wouldn't port 80 be enabled by default? It took me ages to find this post, thanks ;)